# Rspec to test signing out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm using `rspec` and `capybara` in my Rails app and I'm trying to simulate a user logging out of the application, however it doesn't recognize the current users first name to click on.  The navigation is in a partial on each page and I want to have the test click on the users name in the navbar which opens a dropdown and then clicks on sign out.

This is the navigation partial that has the sign out link.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></i> <%= current_user.first_name.capitalize %> <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" id: "signedin" >
    <%= link_to raw("<i class='fa fa-user' aria-hidden='true'></i> Profile"), current_user, class: "dropdown-item" %>
    <%= link_to raw("<i class='fa fa-cog' aria-hidden='true'></i> Settings"), current_user, class: "dropdown-item" %>
    <%= link_to raw("<i class='fa fa-question-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i> Help"), current_user, class: "dropdown-item" %>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <%= link_to raw("<i class='fa fa-bug' aria-hidden='true'></i> Report Bug"), new_bug_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
    <%= link_to raw("<i class='fa fa-gift' aria-hidden='true'></i> Request Feature"), current_user, class: "dropdown-item" %>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <%= link_to raw("<i class='fa fa-sign-out' aria-hidden='true'></i> Sign Out"), session_path, method: :delete, class: "dropdown-item", id: "signout-user" %>
  </div>
</li>
```

Here's the test I'm running:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "A user" do

  def setup
    @user = User.create!(user_attributes(email: "test@testing.com"))
    logout(@user)
  end

  before(:each) do
    setup
  end

  it "should be redirected going to following path when not logged in" do
    visit following_user_path(@user)
    expect(current_path).to eq(root_url)    
  end

  it "should be redirected when go to followers path when not logged in" do
    visit followers_user_path(@user)
    expect(current_path).to eq(root_url)    
  end   

end
```

This is the helper function that I'm having trouble getting to work.  My app has a navbar which has the currently signed in users first name showing, if you click on that link there's a dropdown menu with options, one of the options is to sign out:

```
def logout(a)
  visit root_path
  click_link "#{@user.first_name}"
  click_link 'Sign Out'
end
```

[image]

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)   
  if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id # creates session to login user
    flash[:success] = "Hi #{@user.first_name.capitalize}, thanks for creating an account!"
    redirect_to user_url(@user.id)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting is

> Failure/Error: click_link "#{@user.first_name}"
>   Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>      Unable to find link "Mike"

Comment: What's in `setup`? Is that where you're signing your user in?

Comment: yes setup just creates a user and in my app when a user gets created they are automatically signed in so i was looking to create the account and then sign them out.

Comment: What is the full error you get? Also, just because your app automatically signs a user in when a user is created through the app doesn't mean they are automatically signed in when you call `User.create!` - in fact I would think it's impossible for that to sign a user in (unless `User.create!` is calling some middleware login shortcuts) since it can't set the requisite cookies in the users browser for them to be signed in.  Use `save_and_open_screenshot` to see what the page actually looks like - I'll bet it's not actually signed in.

Comment: I'm creating the user session after a new account is created.  I updated the question above with my create action.

Comment: You explicitly logout that user, so how are they ever signed in? I would think you would need to sign a user in before you test signing them out

Comment: @SMK Calling `User.create!` doesn't call the `create` action in your User controller -  It's creating the model directly.  You aren't actually logging in the user -- check `save_and_open_screenshot` after visiting the root_path you'll see that you aren't logged in

Comment: @ThomasWalpole is correct, in setup you need to either set `session[:user_id] = @user.id` explicitly or go through the create action on the controller (probably preferred if this is an integration test)

Comment: @DanHilton When running Capybara tests with a real browser you don't actually have acess to the session in the tests so you can't do `session[:user_id] = ...` in `setup` - The OP needs to either login by going through the add a new user pages of the site or use something like Devises test helpers to create a new session via middleware inserted into the app in the test environment

Comment: True, Capybara does not come out of the box with that support. OP can use a gem like https://github.com/railsware/rack_session_access to manipulate the session

Comment: @DanHilton Which inserts middleware :)

Answer (score 1):

In your test you create a user, visit the main page withouth signing in and then want to logout. How can this happen if the user is not signed in? Also, your method `logout` is confusing because in there you visit the root url and logout. This method should do only one thing instead of two. What I would do is remove the `logout` method, create a user first, sign in, and in the actual test check if clicing a approriate links logs the user out. To sum up, you get the error `"Element not found"` because the user is not signed in. Your tests actually do not test the logout functionality, they test whether accessing some page results in a certain behaviour which is a completely different scenario. I would do this.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "Logout" do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  before(:each) do
    sign_in(:user)
  end

  it "should display a proper flash message when the user logs out" do
    click_link "Logout"
    expect(page).to have_content("You have been logged out")
  end
end
```